# Visualizar datos SQL como array o json

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un sistema que hace un sql (comprimido. zip) de backup remoto, quiero visualizar parte del contenido , en el servidor remoto, sin tener que volcar el .sql a la bse de datos.
el backup solo se debe visualizar en formato legible para humano.
No puedo volcar cada backup a una DB ya que el server remoto no posee permiso de creacion de basedatos.
es 1 backup para cada usuario, (pueden ser cientos x cada usuario)

Comment: Una posible solución sería hacer a parte del dump en mysql, un volcado en csv de las tablas que necesites consultar y posteriormente convertir el csv a json si es necesario. Este artículo muestra varias formas de exportar a csv: https://hevodata.com/learn/mysql-export-to-csv/

Comment: Un caso de uso extraño: Ver el contenido de un respaldo de base de datos sin usar una base de datos. Si el contenido debe ser aún visible ¿por qué tenerlo en un respaldo?. En términos de sistemas, los errores del usuario es mejor prevenir(los) que solapar(los). No obstante y dependiendo de cómo se hizo el respaldo, podrías editar el script y renombrar las tablas usando la misma base de datos.

Comment: Como dice @Sal, lo que expones en la pregunta es muy extraño. Me pregunto, en caso de que deba ser como lo planteas, si no conviene programar código para que te cree archivos JSON con la información que requieres, antes de que ocurra el backup, así los datos ya existirán en esos archivos. Sea como sea, no le encuentro ni pies ni cabeza a lo que intentas resolver siguiendo esa lógica ... en fin. No seas conformista con *lo que hay*, pregúntate si algunas cosas no deben cambiar seriamente en la lógica y/o en el modelo de datos.

Comment: el sistema es un sistema heredado, en JAVA, que hace backup remoto a un servidor  de archivos.
no hay posibilidad de restaurar el archio aun server mysql remoto.

Comment: Hola @sal
porque un sistema esta en equipos locales, y el servidor esta en nube, pero no  queiren que se restaure los backup.
yopreferiria restaurar o directamente que el sistema replique  cada registro en el server remoto.